# AlamoFire: public key pinning not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, pinning

I am creating a Session manager using a shared instance as below:

```
class Session {
static let sharedInstance = Session()

private var manager : SessionManager?

func ApiManager()->SessionManager{
    if let m = self.manager{
        return m
    }else{

        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "https:api-cat.example.com": .pinPublicKeys(
                publicKeys:savePublicKeys(),
                validateCertificateChain:true,
                validateHost:true
            )]
        self.manager = SessionManager(
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))
        return self.manager!
    }
}}
```

where `savePublicKeys` returns `[SecKey]`.

Even after setting the new ServerTrustPolicy with an empty public key array, I am still able to make successful calls and get data.
Any ideas if I am making any mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `"https:api-cat.payeezy.com"` looks fishy.

Either remove the `https:`-part or add the missing double slash `https://`. The `ServerTrustPolicyManager` only applies the policy when its host property matches the request's host, if those don't match, Apple's standard behavior is used (See [Alamofire Documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/master#server-trust-policy-manager)).

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks ChaosCoder. Just wanted to add this though, the problem was with the '//' missing after 'https:'. You can change your answer to reflect the same.